# How do I integrate a function and plot the result on Matlab?

Tags: batteries, matlab, bode-plot, function

I need to plot a function that has an integrate inside, but I don't know how to do this on Matlab.

---

Function:

\$ SOC(t)= SOC(0) - \dfrac{1}{Q}\int_{0}^{t}i_2(t)dt \$

time is in hours, current is in ampere. So I have:

Constant current: 10A
Q: 68.6 Ah
h = 6.86
SOC(0) = 1

Comment: Do you have a specific EE question or this just maths and matlab?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this question boils down to "*How do I integrate a function*"?

Comment: what is \$ i_2(t) \$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a non-electronics programming question.

Comment: @ScottSeidman you are overreacting. There is no need to close the topic. Plotting functions is a frequent question of electrical engineering students.

Comment: @ScottSeidman According to the help center "programming software for a PC" is not acceptable, however this is more focused on integrating a current, which could be considered on topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to estimate the state of charge (SOC) of a battery.

In this particular problem, you don't even need to bother with integration because the current is a constant function (\$i_{bat}=10\text{A}\$)—so the integral becomes:

$$ \int_0^ti_{bat}dt=10t|_0^t$$

That means, you are just actually trying to find:

$$SOC(t)=SOC(0)-\dfrac{10t}{Q} \tag1$$

Then at t =6.86h, you should be able to find the answer (you already have values for all the unknowns).

Notice that the last term in the above equation has to satisfy \$\bigg|\dfrac{10t}{Q}\bigg|\leq1\$ and that is because the max SOC is 100% (or 1 like you have it —\$SOC(0)=1\$). This problem shows a battery discharging from 100% SOC.

Equation (1) should be easy to plot in matlab.

If for whatever reason, \$i_{bat}\$ was not a constant function and you do need to use the integral, you can use the [integral (click this)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function in matlab—you give it the function in 't' and the limits of integration.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Matlab, but in Octave you can write the generic discrete integration as:

`y[n] = y[n-1] + k*x[n]`

where `x` is the input, `y` is the output, and `k` is the optional scaling factor. Here is the output of the integration of `sin(2*pi.*[0:0.1:10])` looks like, with zero initial conditions and unity scaling factor:

[image: integrate]

If I'm not mistaken, there is a readily available function. This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: To people who are downvoting: the answer not only addresses OP's question, but it also transmits a message, or two -- be sure to not ignore these.

Answer (score 1):

You integrate with the sum() and quad() functions, you'll need to build a time vector like t = 0:0.001:maxtime;
since your function is simply 10, you could built a current vector of i = ones(size(t))*10; then sum along the time intcurrent = sum(i(1:timelength); where time length is the ammount of time you have. This is not as good as a continuous solution.

Comment: "int" isn't what you think it is.  You probably mean "integral", which is a replacement for "quad".

Comment: Yeah your right, quad is way better anyway

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question:

Lower limit = 0

Upper limit = 6.86

i(t) = 10

Q = 68.6

here is the code I came up with

```
% define the integrand
y = sym(10);
% integral
I = int(y,0,6.86);
% initial conidition
SOC0 = 1;
% Q value
Q = 68.6;
% answer
SOC = SOC0 - (1/Q)*I
```

hope this helps.